CodeMirror Merge - Calling a Function on Chunk Approval/Reject
I am using CodeMirror 6, and the @codemirror/merge package. So far I've gotten everything UI related working. However, I can not figure out how to trigger a function when the user has either approved or rejected a code chunk.
Here is what my (JS/React) code looks like:
const editorState = EditorState.create({
  doc: modifiedCode,
  extensions: [
    ...extensions,
    showMergeView ? unifiedMergeView({ original: originalCode }) : [],
  ],
});

const view = new EditorView({
  state: editorState,
  parent: editorRef.current,
});

For reference, I want to run a function to know when to turn off merge view. I am doing this by counting the number of chunks returned by getChunks. However, I can not for the life of me figure out how to run a function when the user has interacted with the merge control buttons.

you almost certainly want to ask this over on https://discuss.codemirror.net first, and only post here once that yields no responses.

After posting on discuss.codemirror.net I was able to come up with the following snippet that listens for accept/revert messages:
const editorState = EditorState.create({
  doc: "// my code",
  extensions: [
    ...extensions,
    EditorView.updateListener.of((update) => {
      if (update.transactions) {
        update.transactions.forEach((tr) => {
          if (tr.isUserEvent("accept")) {
            // handle accept
          } else if (tr.isUserEvent("revert")) {
            // handle revert
          }
        });
      }
    }),
  ],
});

